# Quem regulamenta os padrões web, W3C ou WHATWG? Ou nenhuma das duas?

Tags: html, html5, w3c

Sempre achei que quem comandava os padrões era unicamente a [W3C](https://www.w3.org), mas parece que não é bem isso... vi que também existe a [WHATWG](https://whatwg.org/) *(The Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group)*

Afinal de contas quem regulamenta os padrões web é a **W3C** ou a **WHATWG**? Qual é a diferença entre elas? Tem alguma que manda mais que a outra?

Sempre achei que o Consórcio World Wide Web (W3C) regulamentava tudo, não é isso? Ou ninguém regulamenta nada e os padrões, na verdade, são uma convenção e não são obrigatórios?

Sei que parece básico, mas não entendi muito bem o porquê de duas agências reguladoras.

Comment: @hkotsubo não deixa de ser um questionamento interessante rss. Acredito que sejam as regras a serem seguidas. A documentação tem as regras dos padrões... Mas será que o regulador é absoluto? *Quem regula o regulador*

Comment: Não acho que exista o regulador-master (ou isso é o que ele quer: que pensemos que ele não existe) :-) Mas enfim, no site do WHATWG tem um breve histórico das motivações para o seu surgimento: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/introduction.html#history-2 - só não escrevo uma resposta pq não conheço tão bem todos os detalhes...

Comment: Achei um link interessante https://www.w3.org/2019/04/WHATWG-W3C-MOU.html

Comment: @IcaroMartins eu estava agora mesmo lendo uma publicação no Blog da W3C sobe isso https://www.w3.org/blog/2019/05/w3c-and-whatwg-to-work-together-to-advance-the-open-web-platform/ é uma versão reduzida desse Memorando. Boa dica!

Comment: @hkotsubo teorias da conspiração sempre são bem vindas ! Lerei o link

Answer (score 4):

Lendo a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG) parece que o WHATWG é um grupo que foi formado para fazer os projetos andarem mais rapidamente forçando a W3C aceitar que este grupo existe e começar trabalhar em conjunto ou de certa forma delegar para ele as decisões que depois só seriam oficializadas, pelo menos foi o que acabou acontecendo.

É comum esses órgãos reguladores terem grupos de trabalho, a diferença é que este nasceu espontaneamente para confrontar o órgão principal.

Este tipo de coisa sempre serão definidas por quem age no mercado. Como comparação, existe um dono da Formula 1, mas se as equipes e pilotos que atuam e detém a fama saírem e fizerem outra coisa, só sobra a marca e contratos diversos com quem põe o dinheiro esvaziados (claro se eles conseguirem contratos semelhantes, nem sempre dá certo, a Formula Indy aconteceu isso, criou 2 categorias e as duas acabaram afundando com o tempo, mas era outro nível). Então se quem faz os principais softwares do mercado que permitem a web funcionar decidir operar de forma diferente de quem em tese manda em algo na web, já era, o órgão oficial perde sentido. Por isso a Microsoft fazia o que queria por um tempo. As pessoas reclamam hoje, mas ela tinha o navegador que dominava quase todo uso da web e podia fazer do jeito que bem entendesse, e fez, inclusive coisas que fizeram a web se transformar em plataforma, e ninguém queria inicialmente, e começar concorrer com o Windows, bem irônico.

O W3C ainda regulamenta, ela é oficial, mas agora baseando-se principalmente, pelo menos em parte, no que a WHATWG determinar. Se elas se desentenderem de novo vai na WHATWG, não é oficial, mas é quem manda de verdade, no fim a W3C terá que ceder. É uma pena que tenha acontecido assim.

Não pode um órgão de gente que não cuida do que acontece de real determinar rumos. Sabe o que é colocado no padrão do C e em certa medida do C++? O que os criadores de compiladores, bibliotecas e coisas de infra básica dessas linguagens já fizeram ou estão fazendo. Padrões só devem existir por forças reais, não por imposição "acadêmica", que era e foi muito no começo o que aconteceu com a W3C e por isso sofremos muito, principalmente com CSS. Se tivesse sido criado de forma organizada por engenheiros de campo não teria tantos problemas.

[Discussão](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/W3C). [Acordo](https://www.w3.org/blog/news/archives/7753).