# O elemento <audio> faz parte do grupo "Palpable content" ou não?

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se o elemento `<audio>` faz parte do grupo *Palpable content*, pois segundo o site do [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-audio-element) eles mencionam:

> If the element has a controls attribute: Palpable content.

Ou seja caso se o elemento `<audio>` tiver o atributo `controls` definido ele faz parte do grupo *Palpable content* pelo contrário não, mas no site do [W3C](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-audio-element) eles não menciona que o elemento `<audio>` faz parte do grupo *Palpable content*:

> Flow content.
>
> Phrasing content.
>
> Embedded content.
>
> If the element has a controls attribute: Interactive content.

O elemento `<audio>` faz ou não parte do grupo *Palpable content*?

Comment: Sem ofensas, mas que diferença isso faz para vc? Pq vc quer saber se ele é ou não um *Palpable content*?

Comment: @Hugocsl é que eu estou criando um site de referência e em uma seção do site eu documento todos os elementos, então eu preciso especificar informações sobre o elemento e uma dessas informação é qual o grupo que o elemento faz parte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, qualquer uma das duas tem autonomia para dizer o que quiser, depois, se o browser vai implementar ou não é outra estória... Aqui você pode ver algo bem superficial sobre o assunto [Quem regulamenta os padrões web W3C ou WHATWG? Ou nenhuma das duas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412235/quem-regulamenta-os-padr%c3%b5es-web-w3c-ou-whatwg-ou-nenhuma-das-duas)

Mas já que você quer saber... `audio` com `controls`, se o browser tiver `controls` implementado rss, é um `interactive content` segundo a **W3C** https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/dom.html#kinds-of-content-interactive-content e a **Mozilla**  diz o mesmo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories.

O que diz a **WHATWG**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Se tem `controls` é `Palpable content` e também é `Interactive content`

#### W3C

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então ele é Palpable content?

Comment: @felipecardozo se tiver `controls` sim, isso é unânime tanto par W3C quanto Whatwg

Comment: Muito obrigado!